# How to extract event data from IntermediateEventRepresentation

Tags: axon-framework

I'm writing a context aware upcaster that should extract event data from an `IntermediateEventRepresentation` and store it in context.

I see that `IntermediateEventRepresentation` has a `getData` method which returns `SerializedObject<?>`. `SerializedObject` has a `getData` method that returns `T`, but this return type doesn't contain the event data I expect.

```kotlin
class MyUpcaster : ContextAwareSingleEventUpcaster<Context>() {
    override fun doUpcast(intermediateRepresentation: IntermediateEventRepresentation, context: Context): IntermediateEventRepresentation {
        val eventData: MyEventType = intermediateRepresentation.data.data  // error
        val eventData: MyEventType = intermediateRepresentation.getData(MyEventType::class.java).data  // error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Updated Answer

**TLDR** -
I was passing the wrong class as an argument to `IntermediateEventRepresentation.getData()`. I needed to pass `JsonNode::class.java` rather than `MyEventType::class.java`.

---

My original idea of deserializing to `MyEventType` proved misguided. If `MyEventType` ever changes, or if it contains nested objects that change, you'll end up needing to maintain a record of all those object structures within your upcaster, which is undesirable.

It seems better just to work with the `JsonNode` returned from `IntermediateEventRepresentation.getData(JsonNode::class.java).data`:

```kotlin
class MyUpcaster() : ContextAwareSingleEventUpcaster<Context>() {
    override fun doUpcast(intermediateRepresentation: IntermediateEventRepresentation, context: Context): IntermediateEventRepresentation {
        val eventJson: JsonNode = intermediateRepresentation.getData(JsonNode::class.java).data
        val key = eventJson.get("id").textValue()
        context.put(key, eventJson) // hooray!
    }
}
```

### Original Answer (Bad)

The `SerializedObject` returned by `IntermediateEventRepresentation.getData()` must be (surprise!) deserialized using the appropriate serializer (`JacksonSerializer`, in this case):

```kotlin
class MyUpcaster(private val serializer: Serializer) : ContextAwareSingleEventUpcaster<Context>() {
    override fun doUpcast(intermediateRepresentation: IntermediateEventRepresentation, context: Context): IntermediateEventRepresentation {
        val eventData: MyEventType = serializer.deserialize(intermediateRepresentation.getData(JsonNode::class.java))
        context.put(eventData.key, eventData.value) // hooray!
    }
}
```

**Important Caveat:**
This only works if the structure of `MyEventType` does not change, which cannot be guaranteed.